# cross form validation Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

Hi I wanna do the cross field validation in my form in Angular.
I have this validation function:

```
import {ValidatorFn, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import * as moment from 'moment';

export function DateDifferenceValidation(otherDate: FormControl): ValidatorFn {
  return function(control: FormControl): {[key: string]: any} | null {
    const endDate = control;
    const startDate = otherDate.value;
    const isEndDateValid = moment(endDate?.value).isAfter(startDate);
    if(!isEndDateValid && endDate?.value) {
      endDate.setErrors({endDate: true});
      return {endDate: true};
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

and this component:

```
export class SummaryComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({
    startDate: new FormControl(undefined, Validators.required),
    endDate: new FormControl(undefined, [Validators.required, DateDifferenceValidation(startDate)]),
    locationDesc: new FormControl(),
    description: new FormControl(),
  });
...
```

On the form group on the form control field I'm passing the validator function in the validation array and I wanna pass another form control field to my validator function as a parameter. However, with this solution I'm not able to access the "startDate" - the cross control field. I cannot even use the instance of the form group to access it.

Is there a way how to access the cross field value?

By the way I know those solutions when you pass an object as a second parameter of the new instance of form group with the validator key and validator functions as a parameter. That's not what I want. I clearly want to use the validator only on the particular field and access the other form control field, if it is possible. Thanks for the advices.

Comment: you would've to pass this.form.startDate to the custom validator. And still, it won't work. The only solution is to provide the validator on formGroup instance itself.

Comment: Ok thanks, I know it doesn't work like this with ```this.form.startDate``` it's just what I've been told to do at work. They told me specifically to set the validator on one field and to check the cross field, however I found this impossible. But is it possible to set that validator on one field and somehow pass the form group instance as a parameter to the validator function?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible. And even if it is it would be a workaround and there will be some inconsistency in its behavior. Angular suggests putting the Validator on FormGroup if you want to perform cross-field validation.